# Saving Multiple Shapefiles From the R Environment

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile

I have one SpatialLine file that I have loaded into R that contained 134 features and thanks to the help of the community have figured out how to break the one file into 134 individual SpatialLine files. I have not however, found an efficient way to save each of these files out from R using the writeOGR function. I can do it individually but that takes time, also some of the features have either numbers at the beginning of their names or spaces in their names so that provides another headache in the process.

Here is my code to split the file:

```
     boulder_trails2 %>% 
     group_split(TRAILNAME) %>% 
     walk2(boulder_trails2$TRAILNAME, ~assign(as.character(.y), .x, envir = globalenv()))
```

Here is what I have tried, using a different file:

```
    OSMPTrails <- readOGR(dsn="~/Desktop/boulder_map/raw_data/OSMP_Trails_DIS", layer =   
    "OSMP_Trails_DIS")

    location <- "~/Desktop/boulder_map/subset_trails"

   for(i in 1:nrow(OSMPTrails)){
   # name of file
   name <- as.character(OSMPTrails$TrailName[[i]])
   # change shap to your 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' 
   writeOGR(subset(OSMPTrails, TrailName == OSMPTrails$TrailName[[i]]), 
       location, name, driver="ESRI Shapefile")
    }
```

And I get this error:

Error in writeOGR(subset(OSMPTrails, TrailName == OSMPTrails$TrailName[[i]]),  : 
  Layer creation failed

If anyone has any other suggestions I am open to them as obviously this does not work and I am not really keen on saving out 134 files individually.